# PHP extension enabled but not loaded on Apache

Tags: apache-http-server, php, extension, php-extensions

For some reason, my php extensions are enabled, but not loaded by my Apache 2.4 server. The extensions I am missing are mbstring and fileinfo. I did the installation manually and I wish to keep it that way, mostly for learning purposes.

When I say enabled, I mean that when I run `php -m` in cmd, the extensions are in the list

However, when I run `<?php phpinfo();` from my server, these extensions are not in the list.

In my php.ini file, I have only configured the follwing (related to extensions):

```
extension_dir = "ext"
extension=mbstring (uncommented the line)
extension=fileinfo (uncommented the line)
```

I added the following to httpd.conf:

```
# PHP5 module
LoadModule php7_module "C:/php/php7apache2_4.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "C:/php/"
```

And, in phpinfo(), I see only a single php.ini is loaded, the one from C:/php

Why would my extensions not be available on my Apache server? Do I have to load/enable them manually in Apache somehow?

*Versions: Apache 2.4.39, PHP 7.3.4

Comment: Not sure about a source install, but most distributions use a different ini file path for cli php vs. sapi interface (webserver)

Comment: @ivanivan I'm not sure if this answers your comment, by from phpinfo I see only single a php.ini loaded, and it's the one from C:/php

Comment: Did you restart Apache? If you are using PHP with Apache, you need to restart Apache for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem with my own extensions outside of the normal Apache PHP type of configuration.  What I found is if I don't use Apache as a service and I open a command console to start Apache, it will load.  It's the only way it will load.  Don't use a batch process or the service.

For Windows,

1. press <kbd>Winkey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,
2. type `cmd`,
3. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, and
4. click "yes".
5. Then, cd to your Apache/bin directory and type `httpd`.

I think if you do anything outside the norm,
custom extensions won't work unless you build your own executables.

Comment: One final note my custom extension references another dll that has to be in the httpd bin directory in order to fully function.

Comment: Was just looking at my old replies and realized that this one has an additional item.  Apache needs to be started based on the user since a user account is associated with certain file privileges.  The system account and the user account are not the same thing.